# How to create file repository from which I can link files to other content types?

Tags: 8, files, navigation, entities

I want to be able to "link" files to my content types. Two different nodes in two different content types can link to the same file, so I don't want use file upload field to avoid content duplication.

I also want to have publicly available "repository" where there is a list of all available files and for each file there is a list of articles / nodes to which this file is linked.

What is the simplest way to achieve this. Is there a reference field or something like that?

I would like to have little search field when linking files to content.

Comment: Is that for Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: Drupal 8 @StefanosPetrakis

Comment: All I can think of here is to use Media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the excellent File Browser (https://www.drupal.org/project/file_browser) which provides a very slick interface (see DropzoneJS), for both uploading new files as well as re-using (referencing) existing ones.

As a side-note: Content duplication will not be a problem, if you offer your users the option to upload and re-use. That way, you can stick to the standard reference direction, Content -> File, instead of implementing a File -> Content (which is also valid, but, less used in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments:

[Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module is just the thing you are looking for. We are also using it in our project, it's pretty good and solves all the problems you listed.

It's maybe also important to mention that this is going to be part of the core very soon (8.4.x).